# How can I set the width of the ScrollView content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Im working on a scrollview and I want it to be with paging enabled, but when I try to set a custom width to the content I cant, I need someones help, Thanks!

Heres what Im trying:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    int PageNum = (int)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / 140);
    targetContentOffset->x = PageNum * (int)(targetContentOffset->x / PageNum);

}
```

When `scrollViewDidScroll:` I add a NSlog and Its printing correctly the current page, what does not work is the custom for the paging width:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    int PageNum = (int)(scrollView.contentOffset.x / 140);
    NSLog(@"%d", PageNum);

}
```

Hope someone can Help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to implement `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method to enable `paging` in a `UIScrollView`. To do this, you need only:

- Set `pagingEnabled` property of your scrollview to `YES`. Documentation says about this property: *If the value of this property is YES, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view’s bounds when the user scrolls.*
- Add your subviews (pages) to the scrollview. Their `width`s must be equal to the scrollview's width, to retrieve a horizontal-paged scrollview.
- Set your scrollview's `contentSize` property.

So your code should be something like this:

```
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
NSInteger numberOfPages = 100;

CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat pageHeight = scrollView.bounds.size.height; // can be something else

for(NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
{
    UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * pageWidth, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight)];
    // do somethings with the page view
    [scrollView addSubview:view];
}

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numberOfPages * pageWidth, scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I do not really understand your code and what you are up to. 
This answer may not even be related to your problem, but it may help anyway.

```
targetContentOffset->x = PageNum * (int)(targetContentOffset->x / PageNum);
```

is quite an equivalent to

```
targetContentOffset->x = (int)(targetContentOffset->x);
```

which does not seem to do much but some rounding. If you do this for the side-effects of the rounding then ignore my answer.

Comment: I divided scrollView.contentOffset.x into 140 because thats the width I want (if thats what you dont understand), I tried what you are telling me and its the same :S, thanks

Comment: Of course it is the same. You are doing x=x. What do you expect from that assignment? Again, I am not sure whether this is related to your problem. In the best case it is just a waiste of cpu usage.